# How to allow data truncation in a single DB transaction?

Tags: mysql, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

mysql will throw an error when the inserted data is larger than the destination column. This seems, all in all, to be a positive behavior.

However, I would like to cancel this behavior for the duration of one specific transaction - in this tx, I want truncation to happen, if the data is too large.

Is there a way to disable this behavior, but only for one transaction? Here is [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) of how to this is at the JDBC level:

> Starting with Connector/J 3.1.0, the JDBC driver issues warnings or
>   throws DataTruncation exceptions as is required by the JDBC
>   specification unless the connection was configured not to do so by
>   using the property jdbcCompliantTruncation and setting it to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior depends on the MySQL session variable `sql_mode`. You can change the variable during a connection, and reset it to the original value later. On my system, the default value of `sql_mode` is:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
-- REAL_AS_FLOAT,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,ANSI,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH
```

You can parse this result in your program, remove the item `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`, update the value with `SET SESSION sql_mode='...'`, execute the statements and reset the variable at the end of the transaction.

**Edit by @ripper234:**

Here is the code I wrote in spirit of this answer:

```
private static final disableMysqlStrictMode = 
    ((String)Play.configuration.get("db.url")).contains("mysql://");

...

String originalSqlMode = null;
try {
    if (disableMysqlStrictMode) {
        // Strip away mysql's "strict mode" for this transaction - in case one of the columns is truncated, we don't want the entire tx to fail
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/10606085/11236
        Query query = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("SELECT @@sql_mode;");
        originalSqlMode = (String)query.getSingleResult();
        String newSqlMode = originalSqlMode
            .replace("STRICT_ALL_TABLES", "")
            .replace("STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", "")
            .replace(",,", ",");
        JPA.em().createNativeQuery("SET SESSION sql_mode=?").setParameter(1, newSqlMode).executeUpdate();
    }


    // Save my entity here
    obj.save();


} finally {
    if (originalSqlMode != null) {
        // Restore original sql_mode
        JPA.em().createNativeQuery("SET SESSION sql_mode=?").setParameter(1, originalSqlMode).executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

It can be wrapped in a prettier form if one is so inclined.

Comment: Thanks, I edited your answer to include the code I ended up using.